# How much do I need to trickle my faucet in cold weather (as a function of x,y,z)?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, building-physics

I am told that, in cold weather, I should let my faucet trickle a little to prevent pipes from freezing, especially if some portion of my above-ground pipes are likely to get cold.

Are there any rules of thumb I can use to estimate the flow rate at which I should trickle my faucet to keep pipes from freezing? If such an estimate is feasible to make, what are the most important factors to consider in making that estimate?

In particular,

- do I need/want to trickle all of my faucets?
- how is all this affected by the ambient temperature inside my house?
- is there a good rule of thumb for the temperature at which "trickling will not save you?"

Some more background on my situation: I live in an affluent, temperate area in the United States where the municipal water lines are not at risk of freezing. I do not know the details of how my pipes are routed or how well-insulated they are.

My pipes do not go above ground outside of the building, although they run through a shallow partially-heated cellar.